# need help.Not able to post data

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const Post = require('../../models/Post');

router.all('/*',(req, res, next)=>{

    req.app.locals.layout='admin';
    next();
});

router.get('/',(req, res)=>{

    res.send('It  Works');
});

router.get('/create',(req, res)=>{

    res.render('admin/posts/create');

});

// router.post('/create',(req, res)=>{

//     res.send('worked');

// });

router.post('/create', (req, res)=>{

    let allowComments=true;
    if(req.body.allowComments){
        allowComments=true;   
    }else{
        allowComments=false;

}

   const newPost = Post({
            title: req.body.title,
            status: req.body.status,
            allowComments:allowComments,
            body: req.body.body
    });
    newPost.save().then(savedPost=>{
        res.redirect('/admin/posts');
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log('could not post');
    });
    // console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Could not post i.e console.log('could not post');

Comment: Can you add more information to the question? Where is `newPost` declared?

Comment: I'm learning coding through udemy and there he didn't declared newPost

Comment: print error in catch

Comment: can you help me in correcting this code

Comment: I just want whenever I submit data in form then it print it works

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't not access the `body` data in that way, so you should use `body-parser`

`$ npm install body-Parser --save`

Then add theses lines in your code:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //Before app.use(route)
```

And then access the properties like you are doing.

Comment: mistakenly I send the wrng code:

Here, I declared the newPost

const newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        status: req.body.status,
        allowComments: allowComments,
        body: req.body.body
    });


    newPost.save().then(savedPost =>{

        console.log('saved post');


        res.redirect('/admin/posts');
    }).catch(error=>{

        console.log('could not saved');
    });

Comment: In order to help you i need you to update the answer @ManpreetSingh